# Processing large JSON attributes gives errors in Nifi

Tags: json, apache-nifi

I have a Nifi flow which processes data from the webhose API, webhose returns a whole webpage of text in its result as a attribute in Json. When I try to extract this using EvaluateJsonPath processor and write it to a new attribute it gives me the "nifi processor exception repository failed to update" error, the content is encoded in utf8 and I know that there is a limitation of 65535 bytes for an attribute in Json. Is there a workaround for this.

Comment: Have you tried using ExecuteStreamCommand with JQ?

Comment: No actually, I updated to Nifi 1.2 and it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this limitation should be resolved in Apache NiFi 1.2.0 from this JIRA:

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NIFI-3389

Also, keep in mind that having a lot of large attributes is not ideal for performance.